# Netbeans 10.0 doesn't start in Windows 10 OS

Tags: java, netbeans

I've just downloaded `Netbeans 10.0` and on a Windows 10 64 bit it doesn't start when i execute `netbeans64.exe` (not even with `netbeans.exe`)

I removed all the java installations and installed `jdk-11.0.2+9` and `jdk-11.0.2+9-jre`.

Also change the path in the netbeans configuration file to the right java path.

Configured the environment variables `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`.

When run the app nothing happens.

Somebody else with same issue?

Comment: Did you try passing `--jdk-home \path\to\jdk` (**not** the JRE!) to the .exe?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried just now, nothing happens again. Tried passing parameter --jdk-home using a shortcut.

Comment: Try starting it from the command line, maybe then you can see an error message. The Windows shortcut will hide anything that is written to the console.

Comment: This is the error from command line: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.jshell not found. And this is the command used: netbeans64.exe --jdk-home "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.2+9"

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Are you sure you are pointing It to a JDK not a JRE? You will probably get better answers if you ask that on the [mailing list](http://netbeans.apache.org/community/mailing-lists.html)

Comment: Installed also the version jdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin.exe from oracle but have the same error.

Comment: Works just fine here. Maybe your anti-virus or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect that at the time you installed NetBeans you either had no valid Java installation, or you have changed your Java installation(s) since you installed NetBeans 10.0. In that scenario NetBeans may be unable to start.

To eliminate this as a possibility, explicitly specify the version of Java to be used when  starting NetBeans:

- Locate the file **netbeans.conf**. It resides in the **etc** directory within your NetBeans installation directory.
- It is a simple properties file containing name value pairs, with commented lines starting with a **`#`** character. Open the file in any text editor.
- Locate the line containing the text **`netbeans_jdkhome=`**. If that line starts with a **`#`** character then delete that character to uncomment the line.
- Set the value of that property to the path of the JDK that you want NetBeans to use. For example, on my Windows 10 machine the line looks like this:

  **`netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\openJDK\jdk-11.0.2"`**
- Try restarting NetBeans once you have saved your change to **netbeans.conf**.
- If that doesn't work then locate the NetBeans log file, and update your question with the changes logged to it when you attempt to start NetBeans. That log is named **messages.log**, and is a simple text file. It will reside in a directory named **var** under your user directory. In my case, on Windows 10, its path is **C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\10.0\var\log**, though obviously it will be different for you.

Comment: Had the same issue with 11.0 - my system is a mess of JDKs and JREs though. Manually setting netbeans_jdkhome fixed it though (although with 10 and not 11). Resolving whatever underlaying path cause for this might be a better long-term option, but this is considerably easier and enables version flexibility.

Comment: Had this issue with the Semeru JDK. After changing the `netbeans_jdkhome` to the Eclipse Adoptium JDK, everything worked fine. Thank you for explaining where to find the relevant setting!

Answer (score 0):

Solved...
after trying many (MANY) possible solutions the one that worked was renaming the netbeans folder to "Netbeans10" without any "strange" chars.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt7_6HwCFOU saw this guy and helped me out solved my problem! and it works :)). He put the file on the C drive not inside the (89x)/ programs files. like literally inside the C drive this is how it looks in my folder:

C:\netbeans

Hope it helps.