# Netbeans installation on PopOS?

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-18.04

So I've just installed Netbeans 11.2 into Pop OS. When i tried to run it, this happened
[image: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.2]

I've checked if my java and javac is installed in the system
[image: java and javac version]

So, is there something wrong with apache or java or the system? What should i do? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

UPDATE: Here is the message.log

> INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList]
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/netbeans/lib/ddl/DBConnection has been compiled by a more recent
>   version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of
>   the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)   at
>   org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.doLoadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128) Caused:
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.db
>   jarFile:
>   /usr/share/netbeans/10.0/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-db.jar  at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.prepare(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(Unknown Source) [catch] at
>   org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Warning - could not install
>   module Database Explorer  org.netbeans.modules.db -
>   org.netbeans.InvalidException: StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.db
>   jarFile:
>   /usr/share/netbeans/10.0/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-db.jar:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/netbeans/lib/ddl/DBConnection has been compiled by a more recent
>   version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of
>   the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
>     org.netbeans.modules.dbapi - The module org.netbeans.modules.db would
>   also need to be installed.    org.netbeans.modules.dbschema - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.dbapi would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.dbschema would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.visualeditor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview - The module org.netbeans.modules.db
>   would also need to be installed.  org.netbeans.modules.db.core - The
>   module org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.db.core - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.mysql - The module org.netbeans.modules.dbapi
>   would also need to be installed.  org.netbeans.modules.db.mysql - The
>   module org.netbeans.modules.db would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.mysql - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db.core would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.editor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.dbapi would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.editor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.editor - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db.core would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.kit - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db.dataview would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.kit - The module org.netbeans.modules.dbapi
>   would also need to be installed.  org.netbeans.modules.db.kit - The
>   module org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.visualeditor would also need to be
>   installed.    org.netbeans.modules.db.kit - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.kit - The module
>   org.netbeans.modules.db.mysql would also need to be installed.
>     org.netbeans.modules.db.kit - The module org.netbeans.modules.db.core
>   would also need to be installed.  org.netbeans.modules.db.kit - The
>   module org.netbeans.modules.db.sql.editor would also need to be
>   installed. Warning - could not install some modules:
>     org.netbeans.modules.db - org.netbeans.InvalidException:
>   StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.db jarFile:
>   /usr/share/netbeans/10.0/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-db.jar:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/netbeans/lib/ddl/DBConnection has been compiled by a more recent
>   version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of
>   the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Sorry if the error message is messy.

Comment: Not worked with Pop OS. But just want to point out that Netbeans 11.2 is not something you might want to try as it has the latest unstable features. Netbeans 11.0 is the LTS version. If the LTS version doesn't work, the desktop environment for Pop OS could be the problem. Are you using the default Gnome or something else?

Comment: I use GNOME 3.34.1

Comment: Have you checked the Netbeans IDE Log file? Location is normally in ~/.netbeans/{netbeans.version}/var/log/messages.log. Any clues in there?

Comment: Hmmm... I can't seem to find the 11.2 version inside the .netbeans folder. Probably because i used snap to install it?

Comment: I mean, i just installed it from snap. Not knowing that it was the unstable version. Oh well. I already uninstalled it.

Comment: @Rheza001 Why are you saying you have _"the unstable version"_? NetBeans 11.2 was formally released on October 25, and [you can download it from here](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html). Try getting the current version from Apache, which is definitely not "unstable".

Comment: @skomisa like i said. I just use the command "snap" in terminal to install the program

Comment: @skomisa It's mentioned here: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/index.html
Quote: "The LTS release of the Apache NetBeans 11 cycle is Apache NetBeans 11.0. The 11.1 and 11.2 releases have not been tested as heavily as the LTS release and may therefore be less stable. Use 11.2 to use the latest features and to provide feedback for the next LTS release, scheduled for April 2020. Go here to download Apache NetBeans 11.0, the current LTS release."

Comment: @Rheza001 OK. In that case follow the earlier suggestion in the comments of looking in **messages.log** for the cause of the problem. Can you update your question to show what is in that log? Without that output I don't see how to resolve your problem.

Comment: @anand1st Thanks. I was not aware of that, but even so, I think 11.2 would be more stable than 11.0 simply because of issues found in 11.0 that have been fixed in 11.2. I know that 11.2 was heavily tested prior to release.

Comment: The version that i got here is version 10.0 and not 11.2. So, no luck

Comment: @skomisa The version that i got here is version 10.0 and not 11.2. So, no luck

Comment: @Rheza001 OK, but version 10.0 of NetBeans should still work, and there should definitely be a **messages.log** file containing details of your NetBeans environment, and any issues during startup. Are you saying that file does not exist?

Comment: @skomisa hold on. updating...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201982/discussion-between-rheza001-and-skomisa).

Comment: The problem is that you are using Java 8, but you need Java 11. To fix: [1] Install Java 11, and optionally uninstall Java 8 if you don't need it. [2] Edit file **netbeans.conf** to specify that NetBeans should use the version of Java 11 that you just installed. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643) for details on how to do that. [3] Start NetBeans. It should work now. If not, update your question with the relevant details written to **messages.log** during the most recent start of NetBeans.