# Unable to add new server in NetBeans 6.5.1 IDE

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, server

I am currently having JAVA servlet in my curriculum and for lab sessions we need to integrate Apache Tomcat with the NetBeans IDE. We need to stay version specific, specified in our curriculum. So, we are using Apache Tomcat version 6.0.33, JDK version 1.6 and NetBeans version 6.5.1. I want to add a new Tomcat 6.0 server in my NetBeans IDE. For that I am performing following steps.

Tools -> Servers -> Add Server.

When I click on Add Servers button, the system is supposed to show me a new panel that allows me to select a server and create it. But, in my case nothing is happening. Please help me with this issue.

I have two versions of JDK installed in my system. JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.12. Can this be the reason behind this error.

Updated:

Here's the image of log after I tried to add server.
[NetBeans Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocNtD.png)

Nothing wrong appears in the log.

Comment: [1] To determine which version of Java is being used select **Help > About**. Among the system details displayed is a line that starts with **Java**. [2] If it shows you are using 1.12 then you need to change the Java version used when NetBeans starts up to 1.6. You do that by editing file **netbeans.conf**. See [here for instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643) on that. [3] Update your question to show anything that was written to the NetBeans log as a result of trying to add the server. You can display the log in the **Output** window using **View > IDE Log**.

Comment: I checked the JAVA version in Help > About section and its shows 1.6.0_13. Although I have doubt in the SYSTEM information. It shows system as Windows Vista version 6.2 running on x86, whereas I am using Windows 10 64 bit version. Problem still unsolved.

Comment: OK. Post the content of the NetBeans log as embedded text within your question. Just posting a screen shot of a small portion of the log doesn't help.

Comment: The full log exceeds the character limit of StackOverflow question. As I am new here, I have no idea how to share such a large content. Please suggest me a way to post the entire log in the question.