# Netbeans not installing with JDK 13 and saying my JDK is less than 9

Tags: netbeans, java-13

I have JDK 13 installed in my PC but when I am trying to install Netbeans 13.3 it is showing that JDK 8 and newer is required.

For certainty I tested my JDK version using `javac -version` on cmd and got 13 I can not understand why Netbeans is showing such error.

Comment: I expect you have both Java versions installed in your machine, and Netbeans is finding the wrong one. Can you find out what location each is installed at?

Comment: [1] What version of NetBeans are you using? You state "13.3" but there is no such version. The most recent version is 11.3. [2] NB 11.0 supports JDK 12. NB 11.2 supports JDK 13. NB 11.3 supports JDK 14. [3] You can explicitly set the default JDK version in the NetBeans configuration file **etc/netbeans.conf** [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643). [4] NetBeans doesn't use **PATH** for determining which JDK to use, so whatever `javac -version` displays is completely irrelevant.