# I click on NetBeans icon but just shows me a task bar then it hides, and doesn't open the IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, java-10, netbeans-12

I have a problem with NetBeans 12.1 opening, but not showing anything, just opens on taskbar.

I try to delete it and re-install but it still doesn't work. My Java version is 10.0.2.

This is the content of my **messages.log** file after trying to start NetBeans:

> WARNING [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]:
>
> The extension <C:\Program
> Files\NetBeans-12.1\netbeans\ide\modules\ext\jcodings-1.0.18.jar may
> be multiply loaded by modules: [C:\Program
> Files\NetBeans-12.1\netbeans\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-textmate-lexer.jar,
> C:\Program
> Files\NetBeans-12.1\netbeans\ide\modules\org-netbeans-libs-bytelist.jar];
> see:
> [http://www.netbeans.org/download/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/classpath.html#class-path>](http://www.netbeans.org/download/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/classpath.html#class-path%3E)

Comment: [1] It sounds like Netbeans is crashing during startup, and a frequent cause of that problem is that it can't find a JDK, but you need to provide more details. Locate the Netbeans log file, and update your question with the content that is written to that file when you click the NetBeans icon. This answer tells you how to [find that log file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643). [2] Also update your question to specify the versions of NetBeans and Java that you are using.

Comment: @skomisa I update my question

Comment: OK. Your log extract shows that  the problem is not that NetBeans cannot locate a JDK, as I had suggested earlier. Instead, I think that the problem is that JDK 10 is being used with NetBeans 12.1. That is not a supported combination. From [the Release Notes for NetBeans 12.1](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb121/nb121.html): _"Apache **NetBeans 12.1 runs on JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on JDK 14**, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans release."_ So please try using JDK 8, 11 or 14 instead of JDK 10 to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Once you have installed one of those alternative JDK versions, you should explicitly specify that JDK to NetBeans. That is done by editing the configuration file **netbeans.conf**. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643) for details on how to locate that file, and what changes should be made to that file.