# Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer (WINDOWS 11)

Tags: netbeans, java-20

I am new in using Java and its apps (a 2nd year BSIT student based in the Philippines with little to no knowledge in programming)

I really don't know how to fix this, I've already installed JDK on my laptop (64 bit laptop) and netbeans afterwards but this error kept on popping up.

Thank you in advance!

I've already (kinda) followed some instructions about cmd and stuff but I don't quite get it TT-TT help please

Comment: NetBeans needs to know the location of your JDK or it can't run. See [this answer for details on how to explicitly tell NetBeans where to look for the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643). If that doesn't resolve your issue then update your question with details from the NetBeans log file. The link tells you how to do that as well.