# How to disabled the ligatures of font in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, fonts

I set Cascadia Code font for NetBeans IDE (17). And IDE began freezes sometimes.

I think the causes of micro freezes are ligatures, but I can't find how to disable them. So, how to disabled the ligatures of font in NetBeans IDE?

Comment: Your question is presented as an XY problem; you are trying to implement your solution (disabling ligatures) rather than determining the cause of your actual problem (i.e. The IDE freezing). To determine why NetBeans is freezing the best place to look first is in the NetBeans log file (**netbeans.conf**). So update your question with any recent messages (and stack trace if present) from that log once NetBeans freezes. [See here for details on how to access that log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643) when NetBeans is frozen/closed.