# NetBeans freezes after exiting the debugger (Java/Processing app)

Tags: netbeans, processing

Intermittently, NetBeans 13 freezes up when I exit the Java app I'm writing/running/debugging.  Doesn't even respond to "close window" (the 'X' in the title bar), or "close window" (right-clicking on the icon in the taskbar).  Can only kill it from the Task Manager.

Had the same problem previously in NB 8.2, and does not seem to matter how I exit my Java app (escape key, "close window"/'X', or the "stop debugging" button in NB).

Consistently, everything's working fine in NB until I exit from my app (IDE breakpoints, step/trace, evaluate expressions, etc.).

Any help/suggestions appreciated-

UPDATES:

After it hangs (and gets killed from the Task Manager) the last 50 lines in the IDE Log are all "Debug Main Project" and "Debugger session started", interspersed with lots of "indexing started/finished".  So nothing added when or after it froze.

Java version is 1.8, but learned (below) that NB 13 requires JDK 11 or later.  Switching back to NB 8.2 where the problem, or at least the symptoms, are identical.  Will update if anything turns up in the IDE Log there...

Thanks a ton skomisa!

Comment: [1] The first place to research why NetBeans is freezing is the NetBeans log file. Normally you can open that file within NetBeans using **View > IDE Log**, but that won't work if NetBeans is frozen. Therefore, as soon as NetBeans freezes open that log file in a text editor and update your question with its most recent messages (and possibly a stack trace as well). This link tells you [how to locate that log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643). [2] Also, update your question to specify which version of Java is being used. You must use JDK 11 or later with NetBeans 13.